# Run antivirus as cron job on a particular set of folders

Tags: apache-2.2, anti-virus

How can I run an antivirus s/w as a cron job to check for virus on a particular set of folders  on my server(Apache, Drupal) where I store the files retrieved from users?

Any ideas?

Comment: What antivirus software?

Comment: Sorry.. I have not decided on it yet.. I am open to suggestions even in this case..

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) and set the cron job to run `clamscan /path/to/folder`

Comment: That would be my suggestion if you're on a *nix box.  I'd go one step more though and say move the files to a "clean" folder after they're scanned so you're not always re-scanning the same files.

Comment: Note that there may be some value to periodic rescanning of "clean" files: over time, zero-day threats become known threats.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install an AV client which supports command line arguments and some form of script-able definition and executable update.

[AVG](http://free.avg.com/us-en/download.prd-alf) and [Clam](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) can do this - you need to decide which is more suitable for you.

You may want to reconsider using CRON to launch a virus scan, and instead use a directory change trigger, which launches the scan as the new file is created.  A [perl module](http://search.cpan.org/~andya/File-Monitor/lib/File/Monitor.pm) is available as an example.